# OpenPGPkeyserver No keys found after Submit OpenPGP Public Key

Tags: gnupg, pgp, openpgp, keyserver

When I submit a new Key in http://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net/ it returns 200 OK and the following body:

```
1 key(s) added successfully.
Key block added to key server database.
  New public keys added:
```

Yet, I am not sure if the key was successfully added because nothing is listed after the `New public keys added:`

In fact after that when I try to search for the key in OpenPGPkeyserver it returns `No results found: No keys found`

---

Also when I push the key through the command line with the following command I cannot figure out what is the response from the server:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --send-keys B34A93B1
```

The output is simply:

```
gpg: sending key B34A93B1 to hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net
```

I am using gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.17 libgcrypt 1.8.4.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to my question: `OpenPGPkeyserver No keys found after Submit OpenPGP Public Key` is related with a wrong value passed to the `search` query parameter on `url`:

```
http://hkps.pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?search=***KEY-ID***&fingerprint=on&op=index
```

Here the `***KEY-ID***` should include the prefix `0x....` otherwise it will not find the public key.

Nevertheless I am still confused about the returned message when we submit a new key since no clear information is given after `:`. **Just returning `New public keys added:` and nothing is quite ambiguous**.